# CKEDITOR's source code mode scrambles custom template code

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to allow custom "template code" within the source code editor. My code snippets would always look like `{* anything here *}`. It mostly works, but if used inside an HTML tag things gets scrambled.

I'm already using `allowedContent: true,` when starting CKEDITOR.

Example:

```
<p style="{* some "short code" of mine... *}">Text</p>
```

turns into

```
<p style="{* some " short="" code"="" of="" mine...="" *}"="">Text</p>
```

And

```
<p {* tet_pos_is_inside *}>Fuss</p>
```

into

```
<p {*="" tet_pos_is_inside="" *}="">Fuss</p>
```

Any advise ?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
apparently there was a simple solution to solve my current problem:

```
<p style="{* some 'short code' of mine... *}">Text</p>
```

works !  Note the use of singe-quotes inside the double quotes.
IOW, as long as there is a `<tag attr="val">` then `val` can be anything except containing more double quotes.

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

My advise would be to never use them inside tags, it sounds like a nightmare to configure. What is the requirement you are trying to fill with those?

You could go around this issue with pre- and post processing using classes, data attributes and/or custom attributes. For example you could use something like his:

```
<p class="tet_pos_is_inside_val-12345 foo-val-12345">I love horses</p>
<p data-tet_pos_is_inside="12345" data-foo="">I love bunnies</p>
<p tet_pos_is_inside="12345" foo="">I love cats</p>
```

Comment: About "You could go around..." well ok, depends on the situation but I can't think of a scenario where one of those would not work.

Comment: Thanks, but my website is like ("advanved") blogging where the users would expect the templates to "just work"...  so the question is really WHY does CKEDITOR converts the code at all !?

Comment: I think my answer to that is so that it can maintain a high level of functionality in many browers. CKE extends contenteditable with a lot of features that should all work with many browsers and that also are *very* complicated. Keeping a well defined source is essential to achieving that. Think about parsing the code yourself - what should an HTML parser do when it sees `<p {* `? What should a browser do when it sees that? If this was XHTML, it would break, but in HTML it needs to be interpreted. I think the source control is single best point why CKEditor actually rocks!